# Как вывести текст, который был введен в поле input в тег h3 и при этом, чтобы после перезагрузки страницы текст в h3 сохранялся?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как вывести текст, который был введен в поле input в тег h3 и при этом, чтобы после перезагрузки страницы текст в h3 сохранялся (но если был введен новый текст в input, то содержимое h3 изменялось) ?

```
<input class="searchmusic", placeholder="Введите запрос:", name="search">
<h3 class="TABLname"></h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось вот такое решение задачи.

```
    var input = document.getElementById("in"); //Находим поле для ввода 
    var inValue = localStorage.getItem('input') //Получаем сохраненные данные
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = inValue; //Вставляем текст, который мы сохранили в локальном хранилище

    input.oninput = function() { // При изменении текста в input..
        
        document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = input.value;  // Вставляем новый текст, который мы толькочто ввели
        localStorage.setItem('input', input.value); // Сохраняем текст в локальном хранилище, чтобы вновь отобразить его при перезагрузке
    };
```